# Android PendingIntent not launching activity after opened from background from notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Google FCM to deliver notifications to my app. I am currently sending data notifications and having my android app construct the push notification. I want the user to be able to click on the notification and have it route them to the appropriate fragment/activity.

It is working great except for one flow.
User terminates app -> Receives notification -> Clicks notification -> App launches and data passed correctly to the splash activity from the notification (I'm using a notification activity to broadcast/start intents) -> User receives another notification while app is open -> User clicks notification -> Notification activity, which just previously launched correctly, does not launch.

I'm scratching my head trying to figure out why this could be. My guess is something to do with the contexts being wrong since the app is being launched from the notification, but I've tried to use both "this" and "getApplicationContext()" and neither fixed the issue.

Below is how I construct the notification and pending intent.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra(Variables.INTENT_NOTIFICATION_DATA, "dummy_data");
notificationIntent.setAction(Variables.NOTIFICATION_CLICK);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
        0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Variables.CHANNEL)
        .setContentTitle("New Notification")
        .setContentText("Dummy text")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setOngoing(false)
        .build();
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (mNotificationManager != null) {
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Comment: the first you clicked the notification, it is working fine, but for the second attempt, it is not working fine ?

Comment: @Ticherhaz only if i click the notification while the app is terminated. Google FCM allows for receiving of notifications while the app is not actively running, so anytime i click on a notification while the app is not running (thus launching the app) and THEN click on a notification in the app, it doesn't work. If I open the app normally then I can click as many notifications as I want and it works.

Comment: Are you on the `NotificationActivity` when it doesn't work while the app is running? If yes, try overriding the `onNewIntent()` and see whether you get the new intent details in it, and act accordingly.

Comment: @Shark I am not on that activity when it doesn't work. I tried to override that method just to check and it also is not being called.

Comment: Changing my pending intent flag from PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT has seemed to fix it. I have a vague intuition as to why but would certainly appreciate anyone being able to explain why this would have fixed it.

Comment: Did you later find an explanation to why this is happening, or why FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT fixed it for you? I am experiencing the same situation and the flag did not fix it for me.

Comment: @AmeenAliu sorry it's been a while so am pretty rusty on the specifics of this. Looking at my final code what I ended up doing was using that CANCEL_CURRENT flag and passing the intent to the main activity that I use. In that activitiy's onNewIntent I grab the data for the intent and then route accordingly. I ended up getting rid of the separate NotificationActivity that does the routing

Comment: hmm. Thanks @Jesse

Comment: is that solve? I have got the issue but still have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue some time ago. I managed to solve it by adding a random string to the intent.

```
 val intent = Intent(this, SomeActivity::class.java).apply {
     action = Random.nextInt().toString()
 }
```

With your example it's should look like:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra(Variables.INTENT_NOTIFICATION_DATA, "dummy_data");
notificationIntent.setAction(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt()));
```